# Find unique row sets

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table in Access 2003 that has the following fields

```
Ptr_RateTable
MinOfWeight_Up_To
Adder
```

I need to find the unique values for MinOfWeight_Up_To for any table, without showing the table names in my results.  I am trying to condense tables sizes in the mainframe by finding tables that can be condensed at the same weight breaks.

So for example

```
Ptr_RateTable|MinOfWeight_Up_To
1109LW020|1.00
1109LW020|2.00
1109LW020|6.00
1109LW020|11.00
1109LW020|101.00
1109LW020|128.00
1109LW020|129.00
1109LW021|1.00
1109LW021|2.00
1109LW021|3.00
1109LW021|11.00
1109LW021|36.00
1109LW021|41.00
1109LW021|151.00
```

I would like to see the following as a result and not make another "Profile" with the same weight breaks

```
Profile1|1.00|2.00|6.00|11.00|101.00|128.00|129.00
Profile2|1.00|2.00|3.00|11.00|36.00|41.00|151.00
```

Comment: I do not see how you can avoid table names, but with a crosstab query and some VBA you should be able to achieve something similar. Is this an option for you?

Comment: Come to think of it, the table names thing is a bit confusing. Queries rarely show table names in the results.

Comment: The table names can show up if you have a namespace collision, i.e., two fields in the SELECT with the same base name but from different tables. The SourceTable is always accessible as a property of a recordset's Fields collections, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a function that produces a signature for that table. Something akin to:

```
Public Function GetSignature(sTableName As String) As String

Dim oDB As DAO.Database
Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sResult As String

sSQL = "Select Distinct MinOfWeight_Up_To" _
    & vbCrLf & "From [" & sTableName & "]"
    & vbCrLf & "Order By MinOfWeight_Up_To"

Set oDB = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
Set oRS = oDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenForwardOnly, dbReadOnly)

Do Until oRS.EOF
    sResult = sResult & "|" & Nz(oRS(0))
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop

GetSignature = result

Set oRS = Nothing
Set oDB = Nothing

End Function
```

Once you have that, you would need another routine that assembles a list of the tables, calls the above signature for each table and stores the result in a temporary table. You would then query that temporary table for the unique list of signatures.

It should be noted that gazillions of string concatenations will be very slow. Instead you should look for implementations of a more efficient string builder class that you can use to build the signatures.

Comment: Do you have something against crosstab queries?

Comment: @Remou - I do not have anything against crosstabs where appropriate. However I do not think they are the tool for this particular job. The poster needs a signature of all data values. A crosstab would produce a single column for each value. You could get a signature from a crosstab by concatenating from a certain column across but if you are going to do that you might as well write a function that gives you a signature directly..

Answer (score 0):

Using a crosstab query:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

sSQL = "TRANSFORM Min(s.MinOfWeight_Up_To) AS Min_Weight " _
& "SELECT 'Profile' & Right([Ptr_RateTable],2) AS Profile " _
& "FROM Sample s " _
& "GROUP BY s.Ptr_RateTable " _
& "PIVOT s.MinOfWeight_Up_To"

rs.Open sSQL, cn

astr = rs.GetString
Do While InStr(astr, Chr(9) & Chr(9)) > 0
    astr = Replace(astr, Chr(9) & Chr(9), Chr(9))
Loop

Debug.Print astr
```